# Why getting javascript errors with sample SDK script?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

I have created following simple web resource in dynamics CRM, to use rest API using OData. Please consider, *new_JavaScriptRESTDataOperationsSample* is sample with SDK, I have only created following sample HTML.

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>OData</TITLE>
<META charset=utf-8></HEAD>
<BODY>﻿
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="new_SDK.REST"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="new_json2"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="new_JavaScriptRESTDataOperationsSample"></SCRIPT>
<BUTTON onclick=createAccount();>Click Me!</BUTTON></BODY></HTML>
```

When I click on *Click Me!* button it gives following errors,

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3) Timestamp: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 07:38:45 UTC


Message: 'startButton' is null or not an object Line: 32 Char: 3 Code: 0 URI: http://dynamicscrm01/CRM01/%7B635475719080000809%7D/WebResources/new_JavaScriptRESTDataOperationsSample


Message: 'output' is null or not an object Line: 199 Char: 2 Code: 0 URI: http://dynamicscrm01/CRM01/%7B635475719080000809%7D/WebResources/new_JavaScriptRESTDataOperationsSample
```

Sorry for incorrect formatting, SO not allowing links in block quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the MSDN sample `sample_/Scripts/JavaScriptRESTDataOperationsSample` is connected to the `sample_/JavaScriptRESTDataOperationsSample.htm` web resource.

[Sample: Create, retrieve, update, and delete using the OData endpoint with JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx)

If you look inside the `CreateAccount` function you will find these lines:

```
startButton = document.getElementById("start");
output = document.getElementById("output");
```

so the script is expecting that inside the HTML file these objects are present. In your example you only include the button, but the `sample_/JavaScriptRESTDataOperationsSample.htm` web resource contains the requested objects:

```
<button id="start" title="Click this button to start the sample.">
  Start</button>
 <button id="reset" title="Click this button to reset the sample." disabled="disabled">
  Reset</button>
 <ol id="output">
 </ol>
```